# Suppress Group by Condition

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've a crystal report like this:

```
Page Header
       2013 & 2014 Salesman Performance Report

Group Header
       Salesman: {Salesman}
       Month     2013         2014
Details
       {Month}   {2013Amt}    {2014Amt}
Group Footer
       Total:    {#2013}      {#2014}
```

Result:

```
2013 & 2014 Salesman Performance Report

Salesman: Billy
        2013        2014
Jan     1,000.00    0.00
Feb     500.00      800.00
Total   1,500.00    800.00

Salesman: Keith
        2013        2014
Jan     0.00        0.00
Feb     0.00        0.00
Total   0.00        0.00

Salesman: Candy
        2013        2014
Jan     (200.00)    0.00
Feb     0.00        200.00
Total   (200.00)    200.00
```

Is it possible to suppress the salesman group "Keith" if there're no transaction on 2013 & 2014?

---

Thank you for the suggestions from craig & Siva. There's a problem, if the total sum for a salesman is 0 but there're transactions. How to handle it?

For example:

```
Salesman: Kitty
        2013        2014
Jan     (200.00)    0.00
Feb     200.00      0.00
Total   0.00        0.00
```

---

I can have the finally result now although I'm not sure the method is correct or not.

Create formula field Count1 & Count2 and input the following formula

```
Count1: If {2013Amt} <> 0.00 then 1 else 0
Count2: If {2014Amt} <> 0.00 then 1 else 0
```

Then input the following formula into Group header, details and group footer (section expert> Suppress)

```
Sum({@Count1},{Salesman})=0 and Sum({@Count2},{Salesman})=0
```

Comment: +1 for the best sample (layout and preview) I've seen in the `crystal-report` tag.

Comment: If there are transactions how the sum can be 0? As per your formula your count will return 1 when the transaction is not equal to 0

Comment: Refer to sample "Kitty", the sum will be 0. Finally I use count to calculate non-zero value instead of sum and I can have the correct result. Actually I'm not sure this method is correct or not. Just share with others. Thank you Siva :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to do so, but not with a `running total` field--running total fields can only be used in the `footer`.

Instead, add the following conditional-suppressional formula to the `salesman header`, `salesman footer`, and `details` sections:

```
Sum({2013Amt},{Salesman})=0 And Sum({2014Amt},{Salesman})=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've updated my question. If there're transactions but the total sum is 0. I didn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to supress Group header, details and group footer.

1. Go to the section expert and gor to the forumula of supress then write below code.

   `If  {2013Amt} =0 and   {2014Amt}=0
   then true
   else false.`
2. For group footer write condition on sum of the group.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've updated my question. If there're transactions but the total sum is 0. I didn't know how to handle it.